# JQTouch Switch Pages Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqtouch

I am trying to switch to another 'page' with JQTouch but it does not seem to be working.
My code looks like this:

```
$('#main').on('submit', '#product-form', function() {

                     var jQT = new $.jQTouch();
                    jQT.goTo('#search-results', 'slide');

                });
```

And the error thrown looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'framework' of undefined
j.jQTouchjqtouch.min.js:18
(anonymous function)1:146
a.fn.delegatezepto.min.js:4
jzepto.min.js:4
a.fn.triggerzepto.min.js:4
J.fn.eachzepto.min.js:4
J.fn.eachzepto.min.js:4
a.fn.triggerzepto.min.js:4
Ijqtouch.min.js:8
Ljqtouch.min.js:10
jzepto.min.js:4
a.fn.triggerzepto.min.js:4
J.fn.eachzepto.min.js:4
J.fn.eachzepto.min.js:4
a.fn.triggerzepto.min.js:4
Djqtouch.min.js:1
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass an empty object to jQTouch(), like this:

```
var jQT = new $.jQTouch({});
```